# Compute the 'elbow' for a curve automatically and mathematically

Tags: math, curve

One example for curve is shown as below. The elbow point might be x=3 or 4.
How to compute the elbow for a curve automatically and mathematically?

[image]

Comment: You may want to ask that here: http://math.stackexchange.com/. But in any case you need to provide some context on how the curve is produced and what possible shapes it can take.

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding the best trade-off point on a curve](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve)

Comment: There is an excellent answer to this problem. Check out the link I've posted as a possible duplicate.

Comment: The solutions for finding the best trade-off point on a curve (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve) is a good suggestion. However, this solution depends on the points on the curve. 
I take the suggestion of @ebo and @Chris Taylor by looking for the point with the maximum absolute second derivative which, for a set of discrete points x[i] as I have there, is approximated with a central difference:
secondDerivative(i) = x(i+1) + x(i-1) - 2 * x(i);
[max,idx] = max(secondDerivative);

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might want to look for the point with the maximum absolute second derivative which, for a set of discrete points `x[i]` as you have there, can be approximated with a central difference:

`secondDerivative[i] = x[i+1] + x[i-1] - 2 * x[i]`

As noted above, what you really want is the point with maximum curvature, but the second derivative will do, and this central difference is a good proxy for the second derivative.

Comment: The data provided is noisy.  You'll need to be more careful than that.  Your suggestion might identify, for example, x=12 or x=19.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I take your idea as my solutions.

Comment: Hi, Chris, You got me a good answer.  Can you tell me if there is a reference for this solution? I want to draft a paper and so I need a reference for this solution.

Comment: Can you explain in what conditions this approximation is a decent estimate and in what conditions would be way off?

Comment: "what you really want is the point with maximum curvature, but the second derivative will do". The point about the curvature seems correct, but the second derivative will NOT ALWAYS do (and maybe will never do): think about function like exp(-x) -- it kind of has elbow, but its second derivative does not have anything event remotely resembling maximum where one would expect the location of the elbow.

Comment: Alex Fainshtein is right, it doesn't always work, especially for exp(-x)... The exact example in the question has fluctuations in the signal and the second derivative changes the sign... Answering Omley's question, this approximation is incorrect if the signal is not monotonic.

Comment: One might want to apply a smoothing algorithm first but this method has proven to be reliable in most cases with the data looks like the provided example.

Answer (score 24):

I created a Python [package](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed) that attempts to implement the [Kneedle algorithm](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~barath/papers/kneedle-simplex11.pdf).

To recreate the function above and detect the point of maximum curvature:

```python
x = range(1,21)
y = [0.065, 0.039, 0.030, 0.024, 0.023, 0.022, 0.019, 0.0185, 0.0187,
     0.016, 0.015, 0.016, 0.0135, 0.0130, 0.0125, 0.0120, 0.0117, 0.0115, 0.0112, 0.013]

kn = KneeLocator(
    x,
    y,
    curve='convex',
    direction='decreasing',
    interp_method='interp1d',
)

print(kn.knee)
7
```

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.xticks(range(1,21))
plt.plot(x, y, 'bx-')
plt.vlines(kn.knee, plt.ylim()[0], plt.ylim()[1], linestyles='dashed')
```

[image]

**update**
Kneed has an improved spline fitting method for handling local minima, use `interp_method='polynomial'`.

```
kn = KneeLocator(
    x,
    y,
    curve='convex',
    direction='decreasing',
    interp_method='polynomial',
)

print(kn.knee)
4
```

And the new plot:

```
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.xticks(range(1,21))
plt.plot(x, y, 'bx-')
plt.vlines(kn.knee, plt.ylim()[0], plt.ylim()[1], linestyles='dashed')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Functions like this one are usually called [L-curves](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=L-curve+method) for their shapes. They appear when solving ill-posed problems through regularization.

The 'elbow'-point is the point on the curve with the maximum absolute second derivative.

Comment: Yes, your ideas is the same as Chris Taylor. Thanks.

Comment: Another question is that why the 'elbow'-point is the point on the curve with the maximum absolute second derivative?

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is the point with maximum [curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature). When the slope is much smaller than 1, this can be approximated by the second derivative (as @ebo points out), but this is not always the case.

Comment: But the m isn't even 1. Hint: Look at the axis scales.