# How to determine the K value for k-means algorithm?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I determine k when using k-means clustering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793532/how-do-i-determine-k-when-using-k-means-clustering)

How can we determine the value of K(the number of clusters) for the k-means algorithm ??

Comment: **Use the search function!** This is probably the one most frequently asked question about k-means.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes.

There are various methods, that usually require **trying different values of k** and measuring which worked best.

Here are some duplicate questions you missed:

> [How to optimal K in K - Means Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212690/how-to-optimal-k-in-k-means-algorithm?lq=1)
>
> [K-Means Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353537/k-means-algorithm?lq=1)
>
> [Kmeans without knowing the number of clusters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615665/kmeans-without-knowing-the-number-of-clusters?lq=1)
>
> [K means finding elbow when the elbow plot is a smooth curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955378/k-means-finding-elbow-when-the-elbow-plot-is-a-smooth-curve?lq=1)