# Remove values outside Loess curve limits

Tags: r, statistics, loess

I am looking to remove outliers before I apply a model. I am using a Loess curve to delimit the trend line and have set outlier limits. I would like to remove the rows that are outside the defined limits. Besides doing this with a custom function that takes each point one at a time and checks the local Loess slope etc... is there an easier way?

[image: Loess trend line with limits (1.2)]

```
# Code generating image above
scatter.smooth( idam$T_d, idam$T_x10d)
loessline <- loess.smooth( idam$T_d, idam$T_x10d)
lines(loessline$x, loessline$y, lwd=3)
lines(loessline$x, loessline$y*1.2, lwd=3, col='red')
lines(loessline$x, loessline$y/1.2, lwd=3, col='red')
```

Comment: Be cautious.  If physics doesn't give a good reason to throw away data, then you might be doing a bad thing by throwing out good but less easily handled data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Detecting outliers could be done with help of [DBSCAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/index.html) R package, well-known algorithm used for cluster identification (see [WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) for more details ).

This function has three important inputs:

- x: your data (only numeric value)
- eps: the target maximal distance
- minPts: number of minimal points to consider them as a cluster

Evaluating eps can be done with help of knndist(...) and knndistplot(...) functions:

- knndistplot will plot the eps values on your data set for a given k (i.e. minPts) ==> you could visually select an effective eps value (generally in the knee curve part)
- knndist will evaluate eps values and return them in matrix from. the k input will generate 1:1:k valuations and you could use the result for determining programatically the accurate eps & k values

Next you have just to use dbscan(yourdata, eps, k) for getting a dbscan object with following components:

- eps: the eps used for calculations
- minPts: the minimal number of points for identifying a cluster
- cluster: an integer vector identifying points which belongs to a cluster (=1) or not (=0). The last ones correspond to the outliers you want to eliminate.

Please note the following limitations on dbscan:

- dbscan use euclidean distance and so it is submitted to "Curse of Dimensions". This can be avoided with use of PCA
- dbscan eliminates superposed points which might generate unidentified points. This can be solved either by merging the results with your data with a left outer join or by using jitter(...) function which adds noise to your data. According to the data you displayed, I think it could be the case for your data

knowing this limitations, dbscan package offers two alternative methods : LOF and OPTICS (an extension of DBSCAN)

### Edit on 25 Jabuary 2016

Following @rawr answer, I'm giving an example based on `mtcars` dataset to show how to use `dbscan` for identifying outliers. Please note that my example will use the excellent `data.table` package instead of the classical `data.frame`.

First, I start to replicate rawr's approach for illustrating the use of data.table

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
require(dbscan)
data(mtcars)
dt_mtcars <- as.data.table(mtcars)

# based on rawr's approach
plot(wt~mpg, data=dt_mtcars)
lo <- loess.smooth(dt_mtcars[,mpg], dt_mtcars[,wt])
lines(lo$x,lo$y, lwd=3)
lines(lo$x,lo$y * 1.2, lwd=3 , col=2 )
lines(lo$x,lo$y / 1.2, lwd=3 , col=2 )
```

[image]

Thereby, we can assess that we get the same results independently of underlying support.

Second, the following code illustrate the DBSCAN approach which starts with determining `eps` and `k`, the necessary number of points to identifying a cluster:

```
res_knn = kNNdist( dt_mtcars[, .(wt, mpg)] , k = 10)
dim_knn = dim(res_knn)
x_knn =  seq(1, dim_knn[1])
ggplot() + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 1])  , col = 1 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 2])  , col = 2 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 3])  , col = 3 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 4])  , col = 4 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 5])  , col = 5 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 6])  , col = 6 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 7])  , col = 7 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 8])  , col = 8 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 9])  , col = 9 ) ) + 
   geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 10]) , col = 10 ) )  +
   xlab('sorted results') + 
   ylab('kNN distance')
```

The results are plotted in following graphic:

[image]

It shows that the calculated kNN distance is sensitive to the factor `k` however the accurate `eps` value for segregating outliers is located in the knee part of the curves ==> suitable `eps` is located between 2 and 4.
This is a visual assessment which could be automatized with appropriate search algorithms (for instance, [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve?lq=1)).
Regarding `k`, a tradeoff must be defined, knowing the lower k is, the less stringent results are.

In next part, we will parametrize dbscan with `eps = 3` (based on visual estimation) and `k = 4` for having slight stringent results. We will plot these results with help of rawr's code:

```
eps = 3
k = 4
res_dbscan = dbscan( dt_mtcars[, .(wt, mpg)] , eps , k )
plot(wt~mpg, data=dt_mtcars, col = res_dbscan$cluster)
lo <- loess.smooth(dt_mtcars[res_dbscan$cluster>0,mpg], dt_mtcars[res_dbscan$cluster>0,wt])
lines(lo$x,lo$y, lwd=3)
lines(lo$x,lo$y * 1.2, lwd=3 , col=2 )
lines(lo$x,lo$y / 1.2, lwd=3 , col=2 )
```

[image]

we got this figure where we can assess that we got different results from rawr's approach, where the points located in `mpg = [10,13]` are considered as outliers.

These results could considered as odd comparing to rawr's solution, which works under the assumptions of having bivariate data (Y ~ X). However `mtcars` is a multidimensional dataset where relationship between variables might be (or not) linear... To assess this point, we could scatterplot this dataset, filtered on numerical values for instance

```
pairs(dt_mtcars[, .(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec)])
```

[image]

If we focus only on the result `wt ~ mpg`, we might think it is an anti-linear relationship at first look. But with other plotted relationships, this might be not the case and finding outliers in N-Dim environment is a bit trickier. Indeed one point might be considered as outlier when projected in particular 2D comparison... but inversely if we add a new comparison dimension. Indeed we might have collinearity which could be identified and so strengthen the cluster relationship or not.

My friends, I agree it's a lot of `if` and in order to illustrate this situation, we will proceed to a `dbscan` analysis on numeric values of `mtcars`.

So I will replicate the process presented earlier and let's start with the kNN distance analysis:

```
res_knn = kNNdist( dt_mtcars[, .(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec)] , k = 10)
dim_knn = dim(res_knn)
x_knn =  seq(1, dim_knn[1])
ggplot() + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 1])  , col = 1 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 2])  , col = 2 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 3])  , col = 3 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 4])  , col = 4 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 5])  , col = 5 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 6])  , col = 6 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 7])  , col = 7 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 8])  , col = 8 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 9])  , col = 9 ) ) + 
    geom_line( aes( x = x_knn , y = sort(res_knn[, 10]) , col = 10 ) )  +
    xlab('sorted results') + 
    ylab('kNN distance')
```

[image: sorted kNN distances]

Comparatively to the analysis produced on `wt ~ mpg`, we can see that `kNNdist(...)` produce far more important kNN distance (until 200 with `k = 10` for instance). However we still have the knee part which help us to estimate a suitable `eps` value.

In next part, we will use `eps = 75` and `k = 5` and

```
# optimal eps value is between 40 (k=1) and 130 (k=10)
eps = 75
k = 5
res_dbscan = dbscan( dt_mtcars[, .(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec)] , eps , k )
pairs(dt_mtcars[, .(mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec)] , col = res_dbscan$cluster+2L)
```

[image]

Thereby the scatterplot of this analysis highlights that identifying outliers could be tricky in N-Dim environment, due to complex relationships between variables. But please note that in most of cases, the outliers are located in a corner part of the 2D projection, which strengthen the results obtained with `wt ~ mpg`

Comment: How would one apply a clustering algorithm to time series data?

Comment: @user2398029: time series data could be consider as numeric values as well. For instance, Excel or Matlab define a reference time point and use date format as an alias of a "YYYY-MM-DD" format. Thus you're able to switch from a string value to a numeric value. Another way to integrate time series data is the presence of seasonality over a periode, so you can consider time data as a stacking factor. You could also convert time data as factor by distinguishing year, month, day and so on.

Comment: Of course... I'm asking how to apply a *clustering* algorithm to data that does not form clusters.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the point is : how could you assess that your data don't form a cluster, even if you have a 2-dimensional case (Value vs. Time)? For instance, you can have seasonal effects which aggregates results at certain time points ... For sure, in case you have a strict linear effect, using DBSCAN could be useless in 2D case... but if you have multidimensional data, some correlations might occur and hidden when reflecting your data in a representation with less dimensions. I'm working on an edit of my answer, based on "mtcars" dataset for highlighting this point

Answer (score 8):

You can use `approxfun`

Here is an example with "outliers"

```
plot(wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
lo <- loess.smooth(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt)
lines(lo$x, lo$y, lwd = 3)
lines(lo$x, lo$y * 1.2, lwd = 3, col = 2)
lines(lo$x, lo$y / 1.2, lwd = 3, col = 2)
```

[image]

`approxfun` returns a function using the observed x-values that we can use to interpolate a set of new y-values.

Then, you can set a threshold for calling a point an outlier; here I am using `1.2 * y` as in the original question to identify the extreme observations.

```
f1 <- approxfun(lo$x, lo$y * 1.2)
(wh1 <- which(mtcars$wt > f1(mtcars$mpg)))
# [1]  8 17 18

f2 <- approxfun(lo$x, lo$y / 1.2)
(wh2 <- which(mtcars$wt < f2(mtcars$mpg)))
# [1] 28

## identify points to exclude
mt <- mtcars[c(wh1, wh2), ]
points(mt$mpg, mt$wt, pch = 4, col = 2, cex = 2)
```

[image]

```
## plot without points
plot(wt ~ mpg, data = mt2 <- mtcars[-c(wh1, wh2), ])
lo <- loess.smooth(mt2$mpg, mt2$wt)
lines(lo$x, lo$y, lwd = 3)
lines(lo$x, lo$y * 1.2, lwd = 3, col = 2)
lines(lo$x, lo$y / 1.2, lwd = 3, col = 2)
```

[image]

Since there are a couple steps here, you could package this into a function to make things a little easier:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
with(mtcars, {
  plot_lo(mpg, wt)
  plot_lo(mpg, wt, limits = c(1 / 1.5, 1.5))
  dd <<- plot_lo(mpg, wt, limits = c(1 / 1.2, 1.2))
  plot_lo(mpg, wt, pch = 16, las = 1, tcl = .5, bty = 'l')
})

str(dd)
# List of 2
# $ x: num [1:28] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 22.8 19.2 17.8 ...
# $ y: num [1:28] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
```

[image]

```
plot_lo <- function(x, y, limits = c(-Inf, Inf), ...) {
  lo <- loess.smooth(x, y)
  fx <- approxfun(lo$x, lo$y * limits[1L])
  fy <- approxfun(lo$x, lo$y * limits[2L])

  idx <- which(y < fx(x) | y > fy(x))
  if (length(idx)) {
    x  <- x[-idx]
    y  <- y[-idx]
    lo <- loess.smooth(x, y)
  }

  op <- par(..., no.readonly = TRUE)
  on.exit(par(op))

  plot(x, y)
  lines(lo$x, lo$y, lwd = 3)
  lines(lo$x, lo$y * limits[1L], lwd = 3, col = 2L)
  lines(lo$x, lo$y * limits[2L], lwd = 3, col = 2L)

  invisible(list(x = x, y = y))
}
```

Comment: Isn't the x1.2 factor a little bit arbitrary here?

Comment: @user2398029 are you asking me or the op?

Comment: I just noticed the OP had that factor in his question, so I guess the answer does follow along. Isn't there a way to set this factor in non-arbitrary fashion?

Comment: @user2398029 I think the `lo$y * limits[1]` could be replaced with anything, using a `quantile` or `sd` on the y-values instead of a simple scaling. the nice thing about statistics is that you can do anything! so long as you can justify it

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to go have a look at the `outliers package`. This package allows for identification before analysis happens. This is a very SIMPLE example:

```
library(outliers)
series<-c(runif(100,1,2),1000)
round(scores(series,prob=1,type="chisq"),3)
```

With this function, a multitude of test can be performed and you can set a probability level of being an outlier, that you are comfortable with.

```
series<-series[which(series<0.95),]
```