# 2D Orthogonal projection of vector onto line with numpy yields wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, plot, linear-algebra, orthogonal

I have 350 document scores that, when I plot them, have this shape:

```
docScores = [(0, 68.62998962), (1, 60.21374512), (2, 54.72480392), 
             (3, 50.71389389), (4, 49.39723969), ...,  
             (345, 28.3756237), (346, 28.37126923), 
             (347, 28.36397934), (348, 28.35762787), (349, 28.34219933)]
```

I posted the complete array [here](http://pastebin.com/JeW3kJf4) on `pastebin` (it corresponds to the `dataPoints` list on the code below).

[image: Score distribution]

Now, I originally needed to find the `elbow point` of this `L-shape` curve, which I found thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve).

Now, on the following plot, the red vector `p` represents the elbow point. I would like to find the point `x=(?,?)` (the yellow star) on the vector `b` which corresponds to the orthogonal projection of `p` onto `b`.

[image]

The red point on the plot is the one I obtain (which is obviously wrong).  I obtain it doing the following:

```
b_hat = b / np.linalg.norm(b)    #unit vector of b
proj_p_onto_b = p.dot(b_hat)*b_hat
red_point = proj_p_onto_b + s
```

Now, if the projection of `p` onto `b` is defined by the its starting and ending point, namely `s` and `x` (the yellow star), it follows that `proj_p_onto_b = x - s`, therefore `x = proj_p_onto_b + s` ?

Did I make a mistake here ?

**EDIT :** In answer to @cxw, here is the code for computing the elbow point :

```
def findElbowPoint(self, rawDocScores):
    dataPoints = zip(range(0, len(rawDocScores)), rawDocScores)
    s = np.array(dataPoints[0])
    l = np.array(dataPoints[len(dataPoints)-1])
    b_vect = l-s
    b_hat = b_vect/np.linalg.norm(b_vect)
    distances = []
    for scoreVec in dataPoints[1:]:
        p = np.array(scoreVec) - s
        proj = p.dot(b_hat)*b_hat
        d = abs(np.linalg.norm(p - proj)) # orthgonal distance between b and the L-curve
        distances.append((scoreVec[0], scoreVec[1], proj, d))

    elbow_x = max(distances, key=itemgetter(3))[0]
    elbow_y = max(distances, key=itemgetter(3))[1]
    proj = max(distances, key=itemgetter(3))[2]
    max_distance = max(distances, key=itemgetter(3))[3]

    red_point = proj + s
```

**EDIT** : Here is the code for the plot :

```
>>> l_curve_x_values = [x[0] for x in docScores]
>>> l_curve_y_values = [x[1] for x in docScores]
>>> b_line_x_values = [x[0] for x in docScores]
>>> b_line_y_values = np.linspace(s[1], l[1], len(docScores))
>>> p_line_x_values = l_curve_x_values[:elbow_x]
>>> p_line_y_values = np.linspace(s[1], elbow_y, elbow_x)
>>> plt.plot(l_curve_x_values, l_curve_y_values, b_line_x_values, b_line_y_values, p_line_x_values, p_line_y_values)
>>> red_point = proj + s
>>> plt.plot(red_point[0], red_point[1], 'ro')
>>> plt.show()
```

Comment: If you are using the plot to visually determine if the solution looks correct, you must plot the data using the same scale on each axis, i.e. use `plt.axis('equal')`.  If the axes do not have equal scales, the angles between lines are distorted in the plot.

Comment: Wow, I think this is the trick... let me try quickly

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Well, this was the thing, I feel dumb. Thanks a lot for pointing that out, can you please write it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: OK, answer submitted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the plot to visually determine if the solution looks correct, you must plot the data using the same scale on each axis, i.e. use `plt.axis('equal')`. If the axes do not have equal scales, the angles between lines are distorted in the plot.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have been trying to find the projection for 1 hour. I thought the equation is wrong, I checked it more than 10 times. Eventually, the problem was with the matplotlib, and your answer helped me to figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, is the point at ~(50, 37) `p` or `s+p`?  If `p`, that might be your problem right there!  If the Y component of your `p` variable is positive, you won't get the results you expect when you do the dot product.

Assuming that point is `s+p`, if a bit of Post-It scribbling is correct,

```
p_len = np.linalg.norm(p)
p_hat = p / p_len
red_len = p_hat.dot(b_hat) * p_len   # red_len = |x-s|
    # because p_hat . b_hat = 1 * 1 * cos(angle) = |x-s| / |p|
red_point = s + red_len * b_hat
```

Not tested!  YMMV.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I think the problem indeed lies with `p`, as I used the POINT `p` to make the dot product instead of the VECTOR `p` (which is `s+p`) ! I will try your suggestion and get back at you when I get the result :)

Comment: Aaah, ignore last comment, the vector `p` is obtained by doing `p(50, 37) - s(0,60)` is that not correct ?

Comment: Using your code, I get the same `red_point` that I got previously. weirdly, using `p` or `p+s` both give me the same red point :(

Comment: I edited the question with the code, if you need the full data, let me know and I will pastebin it

Comment: @FloranGmehlin Thank you again!  Since the red point is the one that appears at the wrong location, would you please also add the code for plotting the red point?  I have looked at the posted code in detail and cannot find an error (which is both good and bad news :) ).  Much appreciated!