# Elbow method in python

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

i am trying to implement the elbow method in python on my own to get the optimum number of clusters.
Therefore i summed the inertia's of the different k-means runs:

```
sum_squared_dist = []
K = range(1,30)
for k in K:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0)
    km = km.fit(normalized_modeling_data)
    sum_squared_dist.append(km.inertia_)
plt.plot(K, sum_squared_dist, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('number of clusters k')
plt.ylabel('Sum of squared distances')
plt.show
```

So the next approach would be to find the point, were the curve starts to flatten (which should mean that the first derivation is falling).
Is there an built-in method in numpy or scikit-learn to calculate the derivation from an array?

Comment: Are you looking for [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) ?

Comment: thank you :) did not thought of looking for something like difference

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve