# Why would this Python function break in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

From this question

[Finding the best trade-off point on a curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018178/finding-the-best-trade-off-point-on-a-curve)

I am using the Python solution and it works great if I run it by itself.

But I have a dictionary of these 'curves':

sse{}

```
{'00': [4.998436383771836,
  0.0160165895672664,
  0.004512422186993107,
  0.0013171501024742112,
  0.000788783358847752,
  0.0005498425886621068],
'67':[0.13598930783101504,
  0.04717783658889547,
  0.027547125931827038,
  0.021440839841617088,
  0.016775671441391703,
  0.013185864754748117,
  0.010318462898609907],
```

and so on...

if I run this it works perfectly:

```
curve = sse['67']
nPoints = len(curve)
allCoord = np.vstack((range(nPoints), curve)).T
np.array([range(nPoints), curve])
firstPoint = allCoord[0]
lineVec = allCoord[-1] - allCoord[0]
lineVecNorm = lineVec / np.sqrt(np.sum(lineVec**2))
vecFromFirst = allCoord - firstPoint
scalarProduct = np.sum(vecFromFirst * np.matlib.repmat(lineVecNorm, nPoints, 1), axis=1)
vecFromFirstParallel = np.outer(scalarProduct, lineVecNorm)
vecToLine = vecFromFirst - vecFromFirstParallel
distToLine = np.sqrt(np.sum(vecToLine ** 2, axis=1))
idxOfBestPoint = np.argmax(distToLine)

print(idxOfBestPoint)
```

but when I try to make it a looping function I get weird values that do not match  when ran by itself:

```
for k in sse:
    curve = sse[str(k)]
    nPoints = len(curve)
    allCoord = np.vstack((range(nPoints), curve)).T
    np.array([range(nPoints), curve])
    firstPoint = allCoord[0]
    lineVeceVeceVec = allCoord[-1] - allCoord[0]
    lineVecNorm = lineVec / np.sqrt(np.sum(lineVec**2))
    vecFromFirst = allCoord - firstPoint
    scalarProduct = np.sum(vecFromFirst * np.matlib.repmat(lineVecNorm, nPoints, 1), axis=1)
    vecFromFirstParallel = np.outer(scalarProduct, lineVecNorm)
    vecToLine = vecFromFirst - vecFromFirstParallel
    distToLine = np.sqrt(np.sum(vecToLine ** 2, axis=1))
    idxOfBestPoint = np.argmax(distToLine)
    print(idxOfBestPoint, k)
```

It will spit out something like this:

```
7 57
98 11
6 45
4 50
98 91
98 00
1 62
98 79
7 48
98 12
98 38
98 23
5 37
98 56
98 67
5 25
7 46
98 22
98 49
2 47
98 41
98 78
98 35
98 68
98 14
98 24
1 0
98 42
```

I can't tell if there is some variable not resetting or what would cause it to fail by adding a simple loop?

To be clear it does run, but the calc is putting out '98' as the elbow on the loop, but when ran separately by itself it will be 7 for the '67' curve list, not 98.

Comment: Can you show what the expected output is supposed to be?

Comment: They should all be numbers less than 10.  I'm trying to automatically 'find the elbow' and when all these are ran by themselves it's less than 10.  it's just a large dataset so I'm not sure how to provide the exact set.  I can save the dictionary to file and upload it somewhere if that helps.  Just not sure where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo: `lineVeceVeceVec = allCoord[-1] - allCoord[0]`.  It should be `lineVec = allCoord[-1] - allCoord[0]`.  So what you were spitting out was the last time `lineVec` was assigned to a result and that last value was probably from when you ran the non-looped version.

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I looked at it a dozen times and just didn't catch it.  My excuse is that it's Monday :)

Comment: @user3486773 :D. No problem. I managed to catch it by using a diff-tool.  https://www.diffchecker.com/.  I put in the non-looped version and looped version, skipping the initial assignment in the loop and that was the only line that was different.